# Ruby: Get/set an object's property using a string/symbol

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I get and set a property of an object using a string/symbol?

For example, if I have an object `car` with properties `car.color` and `car.name`.

I know you can do `car.send(:color)` to get its property, but how can I set it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
car.send("name=", value)
```

Or

```
car.send("color=", value)
```

Comment: I love this, I wonder if most other programming languages have a similar feature like this.

Comment: @W.M. Javascript: `car["name"] = value;`

Comment: It might be worth noting that send only accepts a string or a symbol for the property name. I searched for symbol in the specs and found the `it "raises a TypeError if the method name is not a string or symbol" ` spec.

If like me, you have a symbol then can call `car.send(color.to_s + "=", value)` to convert it to a string ... I am trying to find out how I can use the symbol directly though.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5c276e1cc91c5ab2a41fbf7827af2fed914a2bc0/spec/ruby/shared/basicobject/send.rb#L32

Comment: I thought about this more are retyped my comment. I ran out of time so here is a bit more of my thinking... sorry.

When passing a symbol, you can only `get` and not `set`.

I came here in a scenario where I had a method name as a symbol and wanted to use that symbol to `set` an objects property value. To do that you have to convert to a string first and then call the "=" method `car.send(color.to_s + "=", value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
car.set_instance_variable('@color', value)
```